# Use groups in lattice plot with grImport custom symbol

Tags: r, lattice, grimport

I am using xyplot to create plots with custom symbols imported using the grImport package.  To use the symbols with xyplot I am following the example in the grImport documentation:

```
panel = function(x, y, ...){grid.symbols(customSymbol, x, y, units = "native",size = unit(15, "mm"))}
```

I would like to use the groups argument for different colored custom symbols (e.g. redSymbol, blueSymbol, purpleSymbol).  After reading it looks like I would use panel.superpose but I'm not sure how to do that with grid.symbols?

I do know how to add new layers to xyplot with different grid.symbols but I would like to start using groups instead.  Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a modified example from the documentation

```
#Create custom symbol
library(grImport)
PostScriptTrace("flower.ps") #Start with any SVG file and convert to .ps
blackFlower <- readPicture("flower.ps.xml")

#Create red flower
blackFlowerRGML <- xmlParse("flower.ps.xml")
xpathApply(blackFlowerRGML, "//path//rgb", 'xmlAttrs<-',value = c(r = 1, g = 0, b = 0))
saveXML(blackFlowerRGML, "redFlower.ps.xml")
redFlower <- readPicture("redFlower.ps.xml")

#Scatter plot with two groups (black and red flowers)

library("cluster")
xyplot(V8 ~ V7,data = flower, groups=V1,par.settings=list(superpose.symbol=list(grid.symbols(blackFlower),grid.symbols(redFlower))))
```

Comment: Questions that expect the respondents to build an entire example tend to get ignored. I suggest you modify one of the examples in the packages you are using and post it as an edit to your question.

Comment: I added the example from the documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no 'flower.ps' and my efforts to create one are failing. You seem to be having more success than I. Carry on.

Comment: Sorry about that.  You must start with an SVG file (you can get one from The Noun Project) and then convert it to .ps in Inkscape... Lots to ask someone to do.  I was hoping more that someone familiar with lattice and grImport already knew how to use grid.symbols with the groups argument.

Comment: I qualify as someone with more lattice experience but not with grImport.